# Watch you do/doing it [simple present or continuous?]

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, continuous

Is it grammatically possible to use both, the continuous form and simple present in sentences that use the pattern as in the title?

Example sentences:

> I want to watch you wash/washing the car.
>
> I want to see you ask/asking him/her out.
>
> I want to watch you get/getting your hair cut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, **watch you doing** is not the present continuous form but **doing** is a gerund and in the same way,**watch you do** is not the present simple form but **do** is a bare infinitive.
Both choices are correct depending on what you want to say.

1. "I want to watch you wash the car" means that I want to see the action (washing the car) completed.

2."I want to watch you washing the car" means that I want to see a part of the action not the whole of it.

Comment: Thank you! Ironically this is what I told my wife (she is American) and she wouldn't believe me.  So a gerund can never be the continuous form? I thought a gerund is just the noun of the verb but it also has the continuous verb.

Comment: This is from the dictionary: verb
verb: wash; 3rd person present: washes; past tense: washed; past participle: washed; gerund or present participle: washing

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful not to confuse the [gerund](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm) form of verbs, which act like *nouns* and are not meant to describe ongoing action.  "Washing the car" for example, is a gerund and not a present continuous verb:

> On Saturdays, my favorite pastime is [washing the car][eating pizza][playing sports][watching television][etc.]
>
> In the evening he likes *drinking whiskey* and *smoking his pipe*.

Otherwise there's nothing wrong with using the present and the present continuous in the same sentence, as two separate actions:

> While he *watches* TV, she *is washing* her hair.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Does that mean I could say something like ' I want to watch you getting your hair cut'  and if the verb is a noun as well it would be wrong? If the gerund is also a verb, why couldn't I use it then?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is fine but again "you getting your hair cut" is a gerund phrase that acts as a noun, "I want to watch television", "I want to watch the baby", "I want to watch the President giving a speech", etc.